How does USB-A communicate with a USB-C controller?
I want to design my own 4-port USB-A power supply, as shown below.
However, from what I am reading USB-A does not support PD. So I cannot get different voltages or currents.
I want to be able to utilize a USB-A to USB-C to charge my phone at 5 V 3 A and also be able to use a USB-A to micro-USB to charge my devices that have a micro-USB.
From what I am reading the PD communication is done using the CC pins of the USB-C (using a USB-C controller IC), however, the USB-A only has D+ and D-. Hence I am very confused because some of my phone charges show different voltages and currents, such as 5 V 2 A or 9 V 1.67 A but they have a USB-A connector on them.
So many questions are how is a USB-A used as a PD and secondly how can I go about making a USB-A to USB-C to charge my phone at 5 V, 3 A (2 ports) and also be able to use a USB-A to micro-USB to charge my devices that have a micro-USB (2 remaining ports)?


9V/1.67A might be Qualcomm Quick Charge or one of those other non-USB standards.  You'd have to look up what your phone supports to know for sure.  In terms of standard USB, PD over A was technically in the standard but I don't think anything ever used it.

design my own 4-port USB-A  ... USB-A what? ... USB-A hub? ... USB-A power supply? ... something else?

@jsotola USB-A power supply

First misconception : USB PD can be used on Type-A connector. There are even a special Type-A connectors for detecting PD support. The problem is, in practice it is never used by anyone, but nevertheless possible.
Also you likely can't use standard Type-A to Type-C cable for charging a Type-C phone at 3A. The Type-A outputs and connectors are generally not capable of providing 3A. Also standard compliant Type-A to Type-C cables must only advertize the "default" available current which is 900mA. And there is no way to communicate via PD as likely the phone only implements PD on CC pins and not on VBUS like Type-A does - and likely it doesn't.
And it seems that if your Type-A provides those voltagea and currents, it does not use PD but QC for the negotiations.
So as your USB power brick does not use PD and does not provide 5V and 3A, there is no way you can make it provide 5V and 3A. Your phone will likely not even try pulling 3A if it does not know 3A is available and even then it might not want 5V and 3A but less current at higher voltage.
You can use standard Type-A to MicroUSB cable for charging the devices with MicroUSB.

USB PD canNOT be used on Type-A connector. At least the PD in its current form. There used to be early proposals that would use some packet-based communication over VBUS wire, but they ended up dead.

@Ale..chenski USB PD revision 2.0 version 1.3 defines PD for Type-A connector. So PD can be used on Type-A. Simply because nobody never really used it for anything does not mean it cannot be used.

Ok, I see your point. Technically no one is prohibited to design anything to obsolete specifications, as long as it says "PD 2.0 compliant".
